# Terraform deploy module with a condition

Tags: azure, logic, terraform, logical-operators, terraform-provider-azure

**what am I trying to accomplish?**
I am trying to deploy a terraform module only if a input variable is greater than 0

**what have I tried?**

```
var.blocks > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
```

**what was the result?**

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ..\mssql-tf-docs\modules\db\main.tf line 27, in module "diagnostic_mssql_db":
  27:   "Blocks"                      = var.blocks > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
    |----------------
    | module.diagnostic_mssql_db is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "target_resource_id".
```

**where is your example code?**
notice in the part below "main.tf"
section "ds_log_api_endpoints"

*main.tf*

```
# SQL Server Database within a SQL Server Server
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "db" {
  name               = var.name
  server_id          = var.server_id
  collation          = var.collation
  license_type       = var.license_type
  sku_name           = var.sku_name
  max_size_gb        = var.max_size_gb
  zone_redundant     = var.zone_redundant
  read_scale         = var.read_scale
  read_replica_count = var.read_replica_count

  auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = var.sku_name == "GP_S_Gen5_1" ? var.auto_pause_delay_in_minutes : 0
  min_capacity                = var.sku_name == "GP_S_Gen5_1" ? var.min_capacity : 0
}

# Diagnostic setting
module "diagnostic_mssql_db" {
  source                         = "github.com/faraday23/terraform-azurerm-monitor-diagnostic-setting.git"
  storage_account                = var.sa_storage_account
  sa_resource_group              = var.storage_account_resource_group
  target_resource_id             = azurerm_mssql_database.db.id
  target_resource_name           = azurerm_mssql_database.db.name
  ds_allmetrics_rentention_days  = var.metric
  
  ds_log_api_endpoints = { "AutomaticTuning" = var.automatic_tuning > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1
  "Blocks"                      = var.blocks > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "DatabaseWaitStatistics"      = var.database_wait_statistics > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "Deadlocks"                   = var.deadlocks > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "Errors"                      = var.error_log > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "Timeouts"                    = var.timeouts > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "QueryStoreRuntimeStatistics" = var.query_store_runtime_statistics > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "QueryStoreWaitStatistics"    = var.query_store_wait_statistics > 0? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1,
  "SQLinsights"                 = var.sql_insights > 0 ? module.diagnostic_mssql_db.target_resource_id : 1
  }
}
```

*variables.tf*

```
#######
# Name 
#######
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the Ms SQL Database. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = string
}

############
# Server Id 
############
variable "server_id" {
  description = "The id of the Ms SQL Server on which to create the database. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

#######
# Flags
#######

# Audit Log Enabled 
variable "audit_log_enabled" {
  description = "The audit log enabled of the resource."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "log_retention_days" {
  description = "Specifies the number of days to keep in the Threat Detection audit logs"
  type        = number
  default     = 7
}

variable "collation" {
  description = "Specifies the collation of the database. Changing this forces a new resource to be created."
  type        = string
  default     = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
}
variable "license_type" {
  description = "Specifies the license type applied to this database. Possible values are LicenseIncluded and BasePrice."
  type        = string
  default     = "LicenseIncluded"
}
variable "sku_name" {
  description = "Specifies the name of the sku used by the database. Changing this forces a new resource to be created. For example, GP_S_Gen5_2,HS_Gen4_1,BC_Gen5_2, ElasticPool, Basic,S0, P2 ,DW100c, DS100."
  type        = string
  default     = "GP_S_Gen5_1"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("GP_S_Gen5_1|GP_S_Gen5_2|HS_Gen4_1|BC_Gen5_2|ElasticPool|Basic|S0|P2|DW100c|DS100", var.sku_name))
    error_message = "Sku name invalid. Must be GP_S_Gen5_1,GP_S_Gen5_2,HS_Gen4_1,BC_Gen5_2, ElasticPool, Basic,S0, P2 ,DW100c, DS100."
  }
}
variable "min_capacity" {
  type    = number
  default = 0.5
}
variable "auto_pause_delay_in_minutes" {
  type    = number
  default = -1
}
variable "max_size_gb" {
  type    = number
  default = 4
}
variable "zone_redundant" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
variable "read_scale" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
variable "read_replica_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 0
}

##
# Diagnostic setting variable
##

variable "sa_storage_account" {
  description = "This blob storage will hold all Threat Detection audit logs. Required if state is Enabled."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "storage_account_resource_group" {
  description = "Azure resource group where the storage account resides."
  type        = string
}

variable "automatic_tuning" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "database_wait_statistics" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "query_store_runtime_statistics" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "query_store_wait_statistics" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "error_log" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "sql_insights" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "deadlocks" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "timeouts" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "metric" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}

variable "blocks" {
  description = "Retention only applies to storage account. Retention policy ranges from 1 to 365 days. If you do not want to apply any retention policy and retain data forever, set retention (days) to 0."
  type        = string
}
```

Comment: You can't refer to `diagnostic_mssql_db`  before it is created.

Comment: Ok, thank you @cloudartisan it has been resolved. I know it is not optimal but still gets the job done.

`count = var.automatic_tuning + var.blocks + var.database_wait_statistics + var.deadlocks + var.error_log + var.timeouts + var.query_store_runtime_statistics + var.query_store_wait_statistics + var.sql_insights > 0 ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform 0.13 introduced support for `for_each` and `count` to modules.

See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#multiple-instances-of-a-module for more details and examples.

For example:

```
module "diagnostic_mssql_db" {
    count = var.blocks > 0 ? 1 : 0
    . . .
}
```

This will give you 0 or 1 `module.diagnostic_mssql_db` resource depending on the value of `var.blocks`.

Comment: Ok, thank you @cloudartisan it has been resolved. I know it is not optimal but still gets the job done. 
`count = var.automatic_tuning + var.blocks + var.database_wait_statistics + var.deadlocks + var.error_log + var.timeouts + var.query_store_runtime_statistics + var.query_store_wait_statistics + var.sql_insights > 0 ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks a bit confused, but if you think from a different perspective, then it's easy to solve.

It seems you want to create a MySQL database and other resources in the module. But the other resources depend on the condition. Think, all the resources in the Terraform have a count property, and if the count equal to 0. It means you only need to set the count variable for all the condition resources. Inside the module, use the variable `target_resource_id` directly.